# Dagger2 ApplicationComponent not generated(git project included)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, auto-generate

So I'm trying to follow Googles architecture [example](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples) and my daggerappcomponent is not generating. I tried changing up the gradle files but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. First time doing something "advanced" like this(for me at least). I commented out everything from the DI package as I cannot get it working without the QuoteApplication, and I cant get QuoteApplication working without building the project and hoping it will generate necessary dagger files.

```
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.factory().create(applicationContext) //here is the problem
    }
```

Here's the project https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/QuoteAppMvvm 
I tried a lot of different build gradles and I tried cleaning rebuidling and so on. I've read all of the online fixes but nothing has worked. I'm certain it's my fault but it might be a bug or something. My last resort is to ask here. Kinda stuck at this.

Comment: Please provide some error message.

Answer (score 0):

It worked perfeclty fine for me.

1. I build.
2. The component is generated.
3. The buld fails because no import.
4. I import the newly created component. **(import com.example.quoteappmvvm.di.DaggerApplicationComponent)**
5. It works.

package com.example.quoteappmvvm

import com.example.quoteappmvvm.di.DaggerApplicationComponent >>>> **You need this!!!**

import dagger.android.AndroidInjector

import dagger.android.support.DaggerApplication

```
//open class QuoteApplication{
////    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
////
////        return DaggerApplicationComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
////    }
//
////    override fun onCreate() {
////        super.onCreate()
////       // if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Timber.plant(DebugTree())
////    }
//}

open class QuoteApplication : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {

        return DaggerApplicationComponent.factory().create(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
       // if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Timber.plant(DebugTree())
    }
}
```